# How to animate view separately in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created a red rectangle on a black rectangle. I wanna when I press the toggle, the red one scale with animation, and they both move with animation, two animation work separately but not like this:

[image: the animation does not look good]

```
struct AnimationTest: View {
    @State var toggled = false
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .scaleEffect(toggled ? 2.0 : 1.0)
                    .animation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.3), value: toggled)
            }
            .offset(x: 0.0, y: toggled ? -50 : 0.0)
            .animation(.easeOut, value: toggled)
            
            Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $toggled)
                .padding(20.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear the result you expect, can you add some kind of example?

Comment: I want them move vertically together like a bundle, and the red one 's animation work separately , you must know what I mean.

Comment: while it is correct , the red one should scale in the MIDDLE of the black one. may be I doesn't express clearly, but I suppose this was a common animation problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.